# Add list to ArrayList<String> and show on ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to make a ListView from the time that I get from a TimePicker'
I succeed to add the time into a variable.
but when I'm trying to add them into the ListView I don't get anything.

```
    addArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(chart_houres_cosher.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.leassons);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Clicked button

```
    textView.setText( firstHouer + " : " + firstdMinute + " - " + seccoundHouer + " : " + seccoundMinute );
    addArray.add(firstHouer + " : " + firstdMinute + " - " + seccoundHouer + " : " + seccoundMinute);
```

I can see the outcome on the TextView but not on the ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you change the data of adapter you have to invoke [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) to see the effects in the list view.

```
textView.setText( firstHouer + " : " + firstdMinute + " - " + seccoundHouer + " : " + seccoundMinute );
addArray.add(firstHouer + " : " + firstdMinute + " - " + seccoundHouer + " : " + seccoundMinute);
addArray.notifyDataSetChanged();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// once adapter is linked and later data source is modified , notify it
// only then adapter go though the data source 
//and update the listView/RecyclerView accordingly
```

Comment: @Mayli Plus why use same string concatenation again in the `addArray.add()` when you can use `addArray.add(textView.getText())` or as string concatenation is not even recommended to be used with `setText()`, set it to a temp string and pass it to both  `setText()` and `add()`.

Answer (score 1):

And where is your data? From your code you are trying to add an empty Array.

```
addArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You just declare addArray, it dosen't have any data in it. And you are adding empty array into ListView.